# Javascript Click event not firing when clicking on an element's padding

Tags: javascript, click, dom-events

Has anyone ever experienced a similar thing? When I click on the middle area of an `li` element, the click event fires, but when clicking on the padded area towards its edge the event doesn't fire.

I'm binding to `click` on the element.

Super stumped.

Comment: are you sure it's not margin you are talking about?

Comment: Chrome doesn't do anything weird: http://jsfiddle.net/G8uRH/.

Comment: Which browser(s)? Might be by design

Comment: @IanStormTaylor can you reproduce it in [jsFiddle](http://http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: Post your code or a jsFiddle.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, with the same HTML element (```li```), in Google Chrome 22. Is this a thing?

Answer (score 1):

This is no solution, just a workaround, but wrap the whole content of an `li` in a wrapper `div`. Apply your padding to the div and not the li. This solved my issue, but this still seems like a very weird bug to me.

Answer (score 1):

I also saw this happening, but only on iOS.  Wrapping with a div didn't work either.  After some research I discovered that the YUI delegate listener was not firing on that node's padding (though it did everywhere else on the node).  Ultimately, I fixed it by removing that node from the delegate listener entirely and adding a traditional click event listener for just that node.  After that, it worked fine!

Not sure if this will help your situation or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem in Chrome, fixed it by adding `position: relative;` to the element.